# How to replace symbolic function call by indexing

Tags: symbolic, boolean-computation

I have an expression like this:

```
expr = x[2] \[And] \[Not] x[3]
```

I would like it to behave like a Boolean function of parameter `x`. Assume I have:

```
y = {False, True, False}
```

I want to have a function `MyEval` the would give something like:

```
MyEval[expr, x -> y]
True
```

How to do this?

Comment: `#2 && ! #3 & @@ {False, True, False}`?

Comment: That would work if I knew the content  of `expr` in advance, but I do not.

Comment: "if I knew the content of expr in advance" - this is a bit unclear then; how is your Boolean-valued function actually specified?

Comment: The `expr` is actually an output of another function, which I omitted for simplicity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
myEval[expr_, x_ -> y_] := Block[{x = y[[#]]&}, expr]
```

Then:

```
myEval[expr, x -> {False, True, False}]
```

> True

Answer (score 2):

```
MyEval[e_, r_Rule] := e /. r[[1]][n_] :> r[[2, n]]
MyEval[expr, x -> y]
```

> True